# finding repeating numbers in a two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I have a two dimensional array in which I need print in horizontal manner.i.e, diagonally from top to bottom.

```
public class ArrayExample {

    public static int[] array = new int[]{{2,1,0,3,1,6,1}, {2,1,0,3,1,6,1},{2,1,0,3,1,6,1},{2,1,0,3,1,6,1}};
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printArray(4,4);
    }

    private static printArray(int row, column){
      for (int i=0; i < row; i++){
        for (int j=0; i<column;j++){
          System.out.print(array[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
      }
    }
}
```

But I need to print diagonally. Could you please let me know the pseudocode that I can write in Java language.

Comment: what did you expect and what did you get

Comment: The program is working fine for horizontal and vertical but when it comes to diagonal cases, The element to be compared is not been set for diagonal elements. I have added the System.out statements to track the program flow.

Comment: A check of the primary diagonal, from top-left to bottom-right requires a single loop (not two nested loops), since the row and column are the same for each element to be checked. That is, the elements to be checked are `[0][0]`, `[1][1]`, etc.

Comment: Your algorithm is all wrong.  To find consecutive numbers horizontally, you're scanning the numbers horizontally, which is correct.  To find consecutive numbers vertically, you're scanning them vertically.  But in your algorithm to find consecutive numbers diagonally, you're scanning them horizontally, which doesn't work.  I suggest you think about how you would do this if you had to do it without a computer, and write out the method you'd use in your native tongue.  _Then_ translate that into Java.

Comment: @user3386109 No, it's not quite that simple.  You're only checking one diagonal, and I think the problem requires checking all of them.

Comment: @ajb The question says, *"diagonally (either right or left)"* so my interpretation was that OP is only interested in the two primary diagonals.

Comment: @user3386109 I think if you write out the array that he's using as input, you'll see that your interpretation is wrong.  He's expecting to find something, and it isn't on the primary diagonals.

Comment: @ajb I see your point.

Comment: @user3386109,@ajb  The problem requires to scan the complete matrix and find the diagonal repeating elements if there are any for all numbers in the matrix.

Comment: @Pradeep You'll need two nested loops. The outer loop cycles through the starting points for the diagonal, and the inner loop cycles through the offset from the starting point. For example, if the starting point is `[3][0]` and the offset is `2`, then the current element is at `[5][2]`.

Answer (score 3):

To compare both the diagonal you can simplify your logic like this:

```
//This loop is to check the constructiveness for left-right diagonal.
//Because all the diagonal element will have same indexes, so (i,i) can be used.
int temp = matrix[0][0];
int counter = 0;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if(matrix[i][i] == temp) {
          counter++;
        }
        else {
         temp = matrix[i][i];
       }
       if(counter == consecutiveTimes) {
          break;
       }
    }

//This loop is to check the constructiveness for right-left diagonal.
//Here sum of all the row index and column index will be n-1. n is the size of your square matrix.
int temp = matrix[0][n-1];
int counter = 0;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if(matrix[i][n-1-i] == temp) {
          counter++;
        }
        else {
         temp = matrix[i][n-1-i];
       }
       if(counter == consecutiveTimes) {
          break;
       }
    }
```

Comment: why do you need that. I am not sure, whether such things are considered good on stackoverflow. If have any issue with answer, please comment.

Comment: The above program is not working for the array new int[][] {{2,1,0,3,1,6,1},{0,9,6,8,6,0,1},{5,6,1,1,8,2,9} ,{6,5,6,1,1,9,1}, {1,6,5,1,4,0,7},{3,6,3,5,3,3,7}, {3,6,3,3,4,0,7}} where we have number 5 element at [2][0]repeating 4 times diagonally.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //for right-left diagonal.

    public static boolean isConsecutiveFour(order , array){


    int value=array[0][order-1];
    int j=order-1;
    int flag=0;

    for(int i=0; i<order && j>=0 ; i++){
        if(array[i][j]==value){
            System.out.println("Matched : " + array[i][j]+ "at" + i+","+j);
            value=array[i][j];
            flag=1;
        }
        j--;
        if(flag==0){
            return false; 
        }
    }
```

}